# Syncfusion ASP.NET MVC RowIndex

Tags: asp.net-mvc, syncfusion

How can I get the RowIndex when I add row dynamically or while binding it to DataSource?

Can anybody please suggest?

I am trying to add CustomAttribute in following way

`col.Field("Name").HeaderText("Name").Width(90).CustomAttributes(custom => { custom.AddAttribute("name", "'{{ :RowIndex }}'"); }).Add();`

TIA
Manoj

Comment: what you have tried.. can you please post your code

Comment: @SunilKumar - Edited Question and added the code.

Answer (score 0):

Use this below code example for your requirement. Use jquery index for this.

```
col.Field("Name").HeaderText("Name").CustomAttributes(custom =>
                      {
                          custom.AddAttribute("name", "'{{:#index}}'");
                      }).Add();
```